# How to go about creating unique id each time page loads?

Tags: javascript, random, unique

I need to create random unique string, of arbitrary length, every time the page loads, so that I can label stuff around by it, to prevent possible overwriting of existing object properties? I figure the code would go something like:

```
var
   uid = generate_uid();
```

Ty.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right tag ?

Comment: unique in what perimeter ? For the session ? the browser ? All browsers ?

Comment: Duplicate of [generate random string for div id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860853/generate-random-string-for-div-id)

Comment: How about a simple random number, stored as string?

Comment: Why, what would be better choice?

Comment: 'every time the page loads' == for the single session

Comment: The whole scenario is kind of vague. Simple pages with JavaScript attached will result in the JavaScript been constructed anew. I doubt your page reload is just a partial one.

Comment: ... to be  more specific, I'm working on a function that gives an object opportunity to manage a queue of functions, and I need to label the functions somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//  I think I got it
//
function generate_uid( prefix ) {
    var
        tmp1   = "",
        tmp2   = "",
        locase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
        tf     = function () { return Math.random() > .5; },
        r,
        l;

    for (var i = 0, len = locase.length; i < len; i++) {
        tmp1 += ( ( tf() ) ? locase[i].toUpperCase() : locase[i] );
    }
    l = ( tmp1 += String( Date.now ? Date.now() : ( new Date() ).getTime() ) ).length;
    for (
        ; l
        ; (
            r      = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( l-- ) ),
            tmp2  += tmp1.charAt( r ),
            tmp1   = tmp1.substring( 0, r ) + tmp1.substr( r + 1 )
        )
    );
    return prefix ? String( prefix ) + tmp2 : tmp2;
}
console.log( generate_uid("fnid_") );
//
//  fnid_2JGZCMWSyrQaNhD10k83p91LTF073X6oiv9Be5u
//
```