# How to set random id for dynamic created textbox and div

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, css

How to set random id for dynamic created textbox and div.i have to set different id for dynamic created div and textbox.please give id for randomly

my code is here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
 <head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
     return '<input name = "DynamicTextBox" type="text"   />' +
             '<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick = "RemoveTextBox(this)" />'
 }
 function AddTextBox() {
     var div = document.createElement('DIV');
     div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox("");
     document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").appendChild(div);
 }

 function RemoveTextBox(div) {
     document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").removeChild(div.parentNode);
 }


</script>

 </head>
 <body>
  <form id="Form2" runat="server">
  <input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add Text" onclick="AddTextBox()" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <div id="TextBoxContainer">

  </div>

 </form>
```

Comment: Why do you want to give a random id? You can handle the object by itself like you did. The document.getElementById is only to get the element...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860853/generate-random-string-for-div-id

Comment: i want random id for textbox

Comment: @user3931943 see my link. Flagged as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var randomId = 0;

 function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
    var newRandomIdOfTextBox = "dynamicTextBox" + randomId++ + "";
     return '<input name = "DynamicTextBox" type="text" id="' + newRandomIdOfTextBox  +'"  />' +
             '<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick = "RemoveTextBox(this)" />'
 }
 function AddTextBox() {
     var div = document.createElement('DIV');
     div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox("");
     document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").appendChild(div);
 }

 function RemoveTextBox(div) {
     document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").removeChild(div.parentNode);
 }

</script>
```

randomId starts from 0 and every time you add a new text box it will increment by one making it unique..

Answer (score 0):

you can set id ="'sometext'+Math.random();"

Please let me know if this helps